# systemd service is not running on reboot

Tags: docker, systemd

I've written a `systemd` script for starting up `docker` containers using `dcoker-compose` in `ubuntu 16.04 LTS` server.

Here is the script file `/etc/systemd/system/swoop.mongo.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Swoop MongoDb Server container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0

ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /var/www/swoop/docker-compose.yml up -d mongo3 mongo2 mongo1 mongosetup

Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

When I start the service with `sudo systemctl start swoop.mongo.service` It works well.
When I reboot the server, It gets failed and the status of the service is goes to inactive.

```
$ systemctl status swoop.app.service 
● swoop.app.service - Swoop App Server container
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/swoop.app.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Have you enabled it ? `systemctl enable swoop.mongo`

Comment: no, not yet. Lemme try

Comment: @nos thanks a lot, It works. you can write it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `--restart=always` for `docker run` command, If you don't have some special requirements in running containers I would recommend that.

Same concept applies to `docker-compose`:

`restart: always`

Policies:

- `no` : Do not automatically restart the container when it exits. This is
  the default.
- `on-failure[:max-retries]` : Restart only if the container exits with a
  non-zero exit status. Optionally, limit the number of restart retries
  the Docker daemon attempts.
- `always` : Always restart the container regardless of the exit status.
  When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the
  container indefinitely. The container will also always start on
  daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.
- `unless-stopped` : Always restart the container regardless of the exit
  status, but do not start it on daemon startup if the container has
  been put to a stopped state before.

Now as far as your `systemd` service goes, You need to enable that service so it automatically get started after `reboots`.

`sudo systemctl enable <service name>`

Update:

You will need to replace `WantedBy=local.target` to `WantedBy=multi-user.target`

> multi-user.target: Multi-user, non-graphical. Users can usually login
>   via multiple consoles or via the network.

Comment: I also have to change `WantedBy=local.target` to `WantedBy=multi-user.target` to make it work.

Comment: Updated the answer in case we can help others.

Comment: Using the docker restart option is the way to go. I prefer the value "unless-stopped" rather than always. Lets you manually stop a container and not have it unexpectedly restart.

Comment: I've added `Restart=on-failure`, how `unless-stopped` is executed?

Comment: The `unless-stopped` restart policy behaves the same as `always` with one exception. When a container is stopped and the server is rebooted or the Docker service is restarted, the container will not be restarted.